# Excel VBA Sort More Efficiently

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I currently have a sorting script that will check line by line for a certain string. If the string matches, then that line will be copied to that worksheet and the line will be deleted. However, sometimes I need to sort tens of thousands of rows and it can take a long time or will crash Excel. Is there a way to rewrite it to be able to sort more efficiently?

In my code, I have the *With ws2* block copied multiple times with different sheet names

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim firstRowWs1 As Long
Dim lastRowWs1 As Long
Dim lastRowWs2 As Long
Dim searchColumnWs1 As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim check As Variant
Dim strSearch As Variant
Dim foundMatches As Boolean
Dim sDate As String
sDate = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sort")
Set ws3 = Worksheets("Overview")


Set ws2 = Worksheets("sheet2")
With ws2
lastRowWs1 = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
lastRowWs2 = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
firstRowWs1 = 1
searchColumnWs1 = 10
strSearch = Array("john")

For i = firstRowWs1 To lastRowWs1
    For Each check In strSearch
        If check = ws1.Cells(i, searchColumnWs1).Value Then
            ws1.Rows(i).Copy (ws2.Rows(lastRowWs2 + 1))
            ws2.Rows(lastRowWs2 + 1).Columns("A:B").Insert xlToRight
            lastRowWs2 = lastRowWs2 + 1
            ws1.Rows(i).Delete shift:=xlUp
            i = i - 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next check
Next i
End With
```

Comment: If the code works then you should rather ask at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). In general you should abandon the worksheet (that's your bottleneck) and have the data in an array or some other data structure. After that you should implement a sorting algorithm.

Comment: You can avoid to declare `firstRowWs1` and `searchColumnWs1` variables, because their values are constant. also you don't need to use `i = i - 1` You can run your for backwards.

Comment: @VictorK if the code regularly crashes and/or runs infeasibly slow then it doesn't really work

Comment: @JohnColeman Authors question is "Is there a way to rewrite it to be able to sort more efficiently?" instead of "Why it crashes?". For that reason I believe it is best suited for Code Review.

Comment: Range objects have a built-in sort method. If you are actually talking about sorting (and it isn't clear that you are -- it seems more like filtering perhaps) then you could try to use that method. Also -- instead of checking for something line by line, you could use the `find` method.

Comment: @VictorK I can see what you are saying. There is a somewhat fuzzy borderline between the two communities.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of challenge is easily solved with two PivotTables: PivotTable 1 has a filter to only show the thing you want, PivotTable 1 has a filter showing everything else. No VBA, lightning fast, easy to script with VBA if necessary.

PowerQuery (aka Get & Transform) will likely also let you solve this.